# Rewrite $| A \cup (B \cap C)|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

By using distributive law $A \cup (B \cap C) = (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)$ I found out that

$| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|$

And then by using $| A \cup B| = |A| + |B| - | A \cap B|$:

$| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)| \\= | (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|\\=|A| + |B| - | A \cap B|+|A| + |C| - | A \cap C|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$

But this is not correct because in the text book the result is:
$| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|| (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$

The expression above is wrong! It is misspelled in the book.

The correct expression is:

$| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)| = | (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following equality is false :
$$| (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)| = | (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|$$

The general formula for $|U\cap V|$ is :
$$|U\cap V|=|U|+|V|-|U\cup V|$$
Apply this formula with $U=A \cup B$ and $V=A \cup C$.

Comment: I corrected the error. But I still don't understand the final result from the text book.

Answer (score 1):

Is that really written in the book as $| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|| (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$, instead of $| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)| \color{red}{=}| (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$? Because there really should be an '=' there; that's not a multiplication, if that's what you thought it was.

Also, I think the real question is: what do you need to rewrite the original $|A \cup (B \cap C)|$ into? Why is that expression in and of itself not 'good' or 'simple' enough, and what would be 'simple' enough? Indeed, why is the book ok with $|(A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$ when that can be simplified to $|A \cup B \cup C|$?

Comment: In text book we have:  

1. $| A \cap B \cap C)| = |A|+|B \cap C|-| A \cup (B \cap C)|=|A|+|B|+|C|-|B \cup C|-| A \cup (B \cap C)|$  

2. $| A \cup (B \cap C)| = |(A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|| A \cup B|+|A \cup C|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$  

3. $| A \cap B \cap C)| =|A|+|B|+|C|-|A \cup B|-|B \cup C|-|A \cup C|+| A \cup B \cup C|$

Comment: Wait, is that really written as $| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)|| (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$, instead of $| A \cup (B \cap C)| = | (A \cup B) \cap (A \cup C)| \color{red}{=}| (A \cup B)|+|(A \cup C)|-| (A \cup B) \cup (A \cup C)|$? Because there really should be an '=' there; that's not a multiplication, if that's what you thought it was.

Comment: Yes, what I wrote was the text in the text book. That's explain everything, it's misspelled in the text book! It took me a couple of hours and a -2 because of this.

Comment: @Oualid Oh, wow, it was just a misspelling in the book. I saw it in your original post but figured you had just made some typo, but when you repeated it in the comment I got suspicious .. :). Well, you won't get your hours back, but if I were you I would try and get those 2 points back by showing them the misspelling in the book!

Comment: Yes! Good point ;-).